# How to pass variable data into empty dictionaries

Tags: python, django

I am trying to push data into empty dictionaries while doing this I add two for loops but I want to return two loops in one variable.

```
d = {
    "result":[],
    "out":[]
  
}

quest = Question.objects.annotate(choice_count=Count('choice'))
ans = Answer.objects.annotate(solution_count=Count('solution'))

for i quest:
   d["quest "].append(i)
print(d)

for i ans:
    d["out"].append(i) 
print(d)

return Response({'data':{'staus':d}}
```

Comment: I assume you mean `for i in quest:` instead of `for i quest:`.

Comment: Yes your right.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. These loops append to the same dictionary - so you have all in one variable. But maybe first you should use `print()` to check what you really have in `quest` and `ans` - maybe they are empty.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can use `zip` and then you can do your task with one `for`

```
for q, a in zip(quest, ans):
    d["quest"].append(i)
    d["out"].apend(i)
```